# Powershell less than "-lt" evaluating false even though it is true only on certain numbers

Tags: powershell

I have a weird issue occurring. I'm parsing a number from a name, which looks like this: `($env:COMPUTERNAME).Substring(11, 2)`. Said name is usually like abcxyzhij099w. I'm getting the `99` in that example. I then evaluate it using a series of `-gt` `-lt` calls, for example `elseif ($time -ge 60 -and $time -lt 120)`.

My problem is that I'm currently evaluating the number `62`. It successfully evaluates that it's less than `70`, `99`, and `620`, but anything between `100` and `619` fails. I've included an image but I'm at a loss to why this would happen. Manually setting `$time` to `62` allows all checks to pass, but parsing from the name causes it to fail.

I've verified it's length is 2, and `gm` shows it as a `system.string`. I imagine I'm just missing something incredibly small but I haven't run into this before. Any assistance would be appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

PowerShell “casts” values on the right side of a comparison operator to match the type of the left-side value. Thus, you’re seeing the results of a *string* comparison. If you want a *numeric* comparison, try reversing the comparison (that is, instead of `$time -lt 619`, use `619 -gt $time`), or force the left side operand to be numeric (e.g., `[int]$time -lt 619`).

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer and explanation! I never knew that's how PS compared. This fixed my issue, I'll accept your answer as soon as it allows me to. Thank you!!